# How to set EE to ignore a directory running a different application

Tags: htaccess, subdomain

I have another application running in a directory called "calculator" and I can't seem to get EE to ignore it.  When I point to the url /calculator I get a 404.

I have this in my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !calculator/
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried changing these two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !calculator/
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
```

To:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|calculator)$ [NC]
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

I double checked to make sure I don't have any url's "calculator" as well.

**EDIT/Added:**
- .htaccess in /calculator directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode 
# github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25
# commitcomment-118920 
# Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk 
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c> 
  <IfModule mod_headers.c> 
     BrowserMatch MSIE ie 
     Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie 
  </IfModule> 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(calculator) [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Explainations...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !calculator/
```

I think the problem here is that you're not informing it what to ignore by framing in brackets. Also you're specifying the trailing backslash, but that isn't part of the request.

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|calculator)$ [NC]
```

This won't work because it's looking for extensions - note the `\.` at the beginning of the condition, you're also terminating it with the $, so nothing after it will be matched (/ or filename in the folder). Instead it should be:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !(calculator) [NC]
```

This should have worked...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But maybe not if you have a trailing slash (according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite), also I doubt it's the complete request (to access that folder), as I expect you're accessing some file under that folder which may be why the condition isn't matching?!?!

**UPDATE**

The issue raised isn't a problem with the ExpressionEngine .htaccess it's the other .htaccess for the calculator application that's causing the issue.

Change this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ /calculator/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The original isn't rewriting within the calculator folder, it's re-writing back to the web root, which contains the EE install.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for helping out!  When I tried your example with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(calculator) [L,NC]` I got a 500 server error.  And yes, I am actually trying to access a file within the "calculator" folder - /calculator/mortgage - specifically.

Comment: Better than a 404! :) Try: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(calculator) [NC] without the additional L, then if that doesn't work, try: RewriteCond $1 !(calculator) [NC]

Comment: True! I tried both of these rewrites and both returned 404's :/  I also tried with taking everything else out of my htaccess except for the rules for removing index php and trying with the different rules you posted for ignoring the directory = same results.

Comment: Stupid question: Can you remove (or rename) the .htaccess file completely and access the /calculator/mortgage file? Also, how come there's no extension to the file? Is there an .htaccess inside calculator folder?

Comment: I renamed the .htaccess file in the root, and I do still get a 404 when trying to access /calculator/mortgage - this is pointing to the directory for a custom application built on the yii framework.  I will post the contents of the /calculator directory's .htaccess file in an edit to my original post.

Comment: I've updated the answer - the issue is the calculator htaccess.

Comment: YES! That was it, thank you so much for all of your help with this! I did still need to remove the "L" from the EE htaccess file, as you had suggested in your comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(calculator) [NC]`